# Which one of these async calls is not like the other?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, async-await

I suspect I have a deadlock issue, but it's an odd one that I can't rationalize. I have an API that needs to verify a few things in order to process the call. As part of the business logic, I might have to make more of those same calls as well. In this case, if a particular piece of data associated with an entity is not found, we attempt to use a backup (if one is configured), which requires checking other entities. Eventually, the code will hang.

Let's just dive into the code (comments highlight the calls in question).

API Controller:

```
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Get(int entityID, string content, bool? useBackUp = true)
{
    //Some look-ups here, no issues at all

    //This works, but it's this method that has an issue later in the process.
    SystemEntity entityObj =
            await BusinessLayer.GetSystemEntityAsync(SystemEntityID);

    if (entityObj == null)
    {
        return new HttpResponseMessage
        {
            StatusCode = System.Net.HttpStatusCode.BadRequest,
            Content = new StringContent("Entity is unavailable.")
        };
    }

    string text = BusinessLayer.GetContentTextAsync(entityID
            new List<string> {contentName}, useBackUp).Result.FirstOrDefault().Value;

    if (text == null)
    {
        return new HttpResponseMessage {StatusCode = System.Net.HttpStatusCode.NoContent};
    }

    return new HttpResponseMessage
    {
        StatusCode = System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK,
        Content = new StringContent(text)
    };
}
```

Business Layer:

```
public async Task<Dictionary<string, string>> GetContentTextAsync(int systemEntityID, List<string> contentNames, bool useBackUp)
{
    Dictionary<string, string> records = new Dictionary<string, string>();

    //We iterate for caching purposes
    foreach (string name in contentNames)
    {
        string nameCopy = name;
        string record = Cache.GetData(
            string.Format("{0}_{1}_{2}", CONTENT, systemEntityID, name), () =>
                DataLayer.GetCotnent(systemEntityID, nameCopy));

        if (record == null && useBackUp)
        {
            List<int> entityIDs = new List<int> {systemEntityID};
            int currentEntityID = systemEntityID;

            //Here's that method again. This call seems to work.
            SystemEntity currentEntity = await GetSystemEntityAsync(systemEntityID);

            if (currentEntity != null && currentEntity.BackUpID.HasValue)
            {
                currentEntityID = (int) currentEntity.BackUpID;
            }

            while (!entityIDs.Contains(currentEntityID))
            {
                int id = currentEntityID;

                record = Cache.GetData(
                    string.Format("{0}_{1}_{2}", CONTENT, systemEntityID, name), () =>
                        DataLayer.GetCotnent(id, nameCopy));

                if (record != null) break;

                entityIDs.Add(currentEntityID);

                //This call seems to cause the deadlock
                currentEntity = await GetSystemEntityAsync(currentEntityID);

                if (currentEntity != null && currentEntity.BackUpID.HasValue)
                {
                    currentEntityID = (int) currentEntity.UseBackupID;
                }
            }
        }

        if (record != null)
        {
            records.Add(name, record);
        }
    }

    return records;
}

public async Task<SystemEntity> GetSystemEntityAsync(int systemEntityID)
{
    SystemEntity systemEntity = await DataLayer.GetSystemEntity(
        scc => scc.SystemEntityID == systemEntityID);

    return systemEntity;
}
```

Data Layer:

```
public async Task<SystemEntity> GetSystemEntity(Expression<Func<SystemEntity, bool>> whereExpression)
{
    using (EntityContext dbContext = createDbInstance())
    {
        //This is the last line that the debugger in VS 2013 brings me to. Stepping into this returns to whatever called the API method, waiting endlessly.
        return await
            dbContext.SystemEntity.Include(sc => sc.OtherEntity).Where(whereExpression).FirstOrDefaultAsync();
    }
}
```

To recap: I call GetSystemEntityAsync three times. The first two times, it completes successfully. The third time, it hangs. If I comment out the first two calls so they don't run at all, the third one still hangs. If I remove the await and use just a normal FirstOrDefault in the return statement of the data layer method, then everything completes just fine.

Note: I have to keep the GetSystemEntityAsync method asynchronous. I cannot alter it to be synchronous.

What are the possible sources of the deadlock I'm encountering? I'm out of ideas on how to solve it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Which one of these async calls is not like the other?

This one, I suspect:

```
  string text = BusinessLayer.GetContentTextAsync(entityID
            new List<string> {contentName}, useBackUp).Result.FirstOrDefault().Value;
```

Try changing it to this:

```
  string text = (await BusinessLayer.GetContentTextAsync(entityID
            new List<string> {contentName}, useBackUp)).FirstOrDefault().Value;
```

The possible source of the deadlock is described by Stephen Cleary in his ["Don't Block on Async Code"](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html) blog post.

Comment: Huh, I did not expect that line to be doing the blocking. FirstOrDefaultAsync doesn't seem to exist in that context. But, awaiting that into a Dictionary and then checking the dictionary to decide what to return works just fine. Thanks.

Comment: @Ellesedil, glad it helped. I just assumed `FirstOrDefaultAsync` might be applicable, apparently it is not. Anyhow, watch out for `.Result` or `.Wait()` anywhere else in your code.